# Multiple Rewrite rules in the same URL

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-8.5

I have my rewrite rule below but I can not understand why my second rule is not working. When I disable the first, it will work properly. Is there a limitation if the url of two rules are exactly the same? Take note that in my first condition I am trying to map a request to NuxtJS if a Baidu spider crawls our website otherwise just serve the static HTML files on the wwwroot directory

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:3000/{R:1}" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^((?Baidu).)*$" />
        </conditions>
    </rule>
    <rule name="StaticHTMLForBaiduCrawler" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^((?!Baidu).)*$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/index.html" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such a limitation.

Your first pattern was syntactically invalid, so an error occurs.

> The expression "^((?Baidu).)*$" has a syntax that is not valid.

Since you don't need an exact match, a simple pattern like `Baidu` just works. Take a look at the following rules and note the `negate="true"`.

```xml
<rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:3000/{R:1}" />
        <conditions>
            <!-- if user agent contains Baidu -->
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="Baidu" />
        </conditions>
    </rule>
    <rule name="StaticHTMLForBaiduCrawler" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
            <!-- if user agent does not contain Baidu -->
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="Baidu" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/index.html" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

Comment: Ok let me try this one